# Is there setting to automatically cast a inf to nan option in polars?

Tags: python-polars

We know in pandas, we can set

pd.set_option('use_inf_as_na', True) to make sure inf is automatically casted to nan

Is there a similar option in polars?

Answer (score 2):

Not automatically, that would be a very expensive setting as well.

But you can convert infinite values to `NaN` if you wish.

```py
pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [float("inf"), 1.0, 2.0]
}).with_column(
    pl.when(pl.col("a").is_infinite()).then(float("nan")).otherwise(pl.col("a")).keep_name()
)
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ f64 │
╞═════╡
│ NaN │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0 │
└─────┘
```

Note that the floating point `NaN` does not mean missing data in polars. So it might make more sense to replace with `None` if you want other algorithms to treat it as missing.